# Duplicates Not Highlighted

Tags: qgis, overlay, nearest-neighbor, geometry-generator, duplication

Actually I am using Geometry Generator and a small script for displaying duplicate values in the data. But some duplications are not highlighted. Don't know why its happening. can any one suggest any solution for that.

Script using:

```
if ( 
    "name" =
    attribute (
        get_feature_by_id (
            @layer,  
            array_first (
                overlay_nearest( @layer, $id)
            )
        ), 
        'name' ) , 
        $geometry, 
        '')
```

[image: Process]
[image: Duplicates Not Higlighted]
[image: Single Duplicate Highlighted]

Answer (score 3):

It is not working as expected because one of the duplicate is closest to a point having a different name

Instead, it is possible to get multiple nearby points - with a max distance - and to count if there are duplicated names.

```
if ( 
 array_length( 
   array_filter( 
    overlay_nearest(
       @layer,"name",
       limit:=100, 
       max_distance:=10),
    @element= "name"))
    >1,
 $geometry, '')
```

`overlay_nearest`:

- `max_distance` restrict the search radius (in map units).
- `limit`: how many points to consider (`-1` would have been ideal but I couldn't make it work. Use a large enough value to go over the "nearby but with a different name" points).
- `"name"` return an array of found names.

`array_filter`: keep only names being the same as the current feature name (including itself!)

`array_length .. >1`: since the current feature name is returned, look for duplicates (or more)

[image]

Comment: I use the script which you have used but duplicate data is not get highlighted as you shown in your screenshot

Comment: @BrunoB have you adjusted the `max_distance` value to a meaningful one? Remember it is in map-units (meters, degree etc)

Comment: Yes I did it as you said